# Capped Array in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm new to Spring Data MongoDB and wondering if you could help me. Basically, what I want to achieve is to limit the size of an embedded array in my document. I've seen other post but it's not using the spring data mongodb ( 
[Saving with Java springdata a mongoDB document with capped array ($slice and $sort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032246/saving-with-java-springdata-a-mongodb-document-with-capped-array-slice-and-so), [MongoDB 2.4's "Limit Number of Elements in an Array after an Update" using C# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787498/mongodb-2-4s-limit-number-of-elements-in-an-array-after-an-update-using-c-sha) ).

```
Sample Document:
{

  _id: 1,
  scores: [
     { attempt: 1, score: 10 },
     { attempt: 2 , score:8 }
         ]
}
```

`updateScore() {
     Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
     query.fields().slice("scores", -3);
     Update update = new Update();
     update.push("scores", scores);
     mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update, MyDocument.class);
 }`

After calling updateScore method, I could see that new scores were appended and it's size exceeds 3.

```
     <!-- mongodb java driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope to hear your comments and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your update to something like this:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
query.fields().slice("scores", -3);
Update update = new Update();
update.push("scores", scores);
update.push("scores", new BasicDBObject("$each", scores).append("$slice", -3));
mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update, MyDocument.class);
```

**$slice** within within a **push** is not yet supported by spring-data -> https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-832

Answer (score 0):

update.push("scores").slice(-3).each(scores)

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.